# How to incorparate scrollbar inside qtip?

Tags: jquery, css, css-tables, qtip

What I am trying here is putting a table inside the qtip and displaying it. But I want that table to have a fixed height and `overflow:auto` after that i.e. if it exceeds the given height, but somehow I am not able to do so.

Here is what I did

```
#tableId {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But the table seems to be unhanged(note that table is shown inside a 'qtip'.Do I have to incude some property of qtip or some CSS changes need to done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the table within a `div`, styled with the CSS you have given for the `table` element. I've never used qtip but whenever I haven't been able to use the `overflow` properties on an element, wrapping it in a `div` usually works.